# Collapse each div with one function

Tags: jquery

Can someone quickly **point out what I'm doing wrong and why** ?
My intention is to have ***each*** `.learnmore` class to expand their own `.more-content` upon click.

**jQ**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  

      //Toggle function
      $(".learnmore").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".more-content").slideToggle(500)
        return false;
      });  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>Whatsup Stack!</h2>
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="Stack Overflow" />
<p>Quick, lorem Ipsum</p>
<p><a href="#" class="learnmore">Learn More</a></p>
<div class="more-content">
  <p>Quick, lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Quick, lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<!-- eo : more-content --> 

​
```

Comment: Could we see the HTML?  It would be useful in determining the issue

Comment: Go to this link. This is a pretty easy solution that is solved here: http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/

Comment: @SirB updated my answer based on the markup. You just need a `.parent('p')` before your `next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its not a child of the element you are clicking you need to traverse up to the `.parent` first. Then since its the next `.more-content` after the parent you can select it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/VH2Ug/2/)**

```
  //Toggle function
  $(".learnmore").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('p').next(".more-content").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: you sir are a genius...one more question since your answer helped me. Why doesn't  `$(this).each(".more-content").slideToggle(500);` work?

Comment: Because `.each` needs to be called with a function, so like `$('.more-content').each(function(){$(this).slideToggle(500)})` but that will toggle every one on the page at once. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.

```
$(this).find(".more-content").slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: Because: `.more-content` is probably not the next element in `.learnmore`. [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only finds the next IF the selector is ok.